# env parameter problem when running third-party images in docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables, imgproxy

I used docker to get the imgproxy image and I need to specify some environment variables when I run the image.Such as:

```shell
docker run --name imgproxy -p 8080:8080 \
  -e IMGPROXY_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
  -e IMGPROXY_SALT=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
  -e IMGPROXY_MAX_ANIMATION_FRAMES=2 \
  -e IMGPROXY_ENABLE_AVIF_DETECTION=true \
  -e IMGPROXY_ENABLE_WEBP_DETECTION=true \
  -e IMGPROXY_PREFERRED_FORMATS=avif \
  -d darthsim/imgproxy
```

In this case, the command is too long and not suitable for subsequent modification, and there is no configuration file that can store these environment variables.

I tried to find the Dockerfile and docker-compose files, but unfortunately, I didn't find them.

Comment: How should I configure these environment variables using files instead of typing them when using commands.

Comment: Did you try `--env-file`? See [Set environment variables (-e, --env, --env-file)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#env)

Comment: This probably answers my question. Let me test it

Comment: My problem has been solved, thank you.